# How to read the scale values from a SVGTransform object?

Tags: javascript, svg, matrix

The [`SVGTransform` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTransform) has a `setScale` method. But how to do the opposite? How to read the scale values from a `SVGTransform` object?

Comment: wahoo .. I didn't even know such a library could exist! thank you. And even The tag here on SO is not filled in!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

[image]

This does it:

```js
function getScale (transform)
{
  if (!(transform.type == SVGTransform.SVG_TRANSFORM_SCALE))
    throw new TypeError ('Not a scale transformation.');
  let matrix = transform.matrix;
  return {sx: matrix.a, sy: matrix.d};
}
```